# Is there a way to set font tracking (i.e. spacing) inside a custom SwiftUI ButtonStyle?

Tags: swiftui, fonts, swiftui-button, swiftui-text

In SwiftUI you can set font tracking (spacing between letters) on a `Text` `View` using the `tracking` View modifier:

```
Text("Hello, World!")
  .tracking(10)
```

If you have a `Button` and apply your custom `ButtonStyle` you can do all kinds of modifications to the style of the button, but since the `configuration.label` is not an instance of `Text` but rather `ButtonStyleConfiguration.Label`, I don't have direct access to apply `tracking`. Is there a way to do this without having to set it on the `Button`'s `label` `View` directly? It seems like something you ought to be able to do since it's a style-related thing but I don't see how to accomplish it.

```
public struct MyStyle: ButtonStyle {
    public func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
          // (if I tried to put `.tracking` here it wouldn't work because it isn't Text)
          .foregroundColor(Color.red)
          .clipShape(Capsule())
          // … etc.
    }
}
```

[ViewModifier to change both font and tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70181312/viewmodifier-to-change-both-font-and-tracking) looks ~ related but no relevant answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `ButtonStyleConfiguration.Label` is not matched to `Text`, but it is your style you can ignore standard label, and request own by interface contract, exactly which you need (`Text` in this case), like in below demo

```
public struct MyStyle: ButtonStyle {
    let label: Text                   // << here !!

    public func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        label               // << here !!
            .tracking(10)
            .foregroundColor(configuration.isPressed ? .black : .red)
            .clipShape(Capsule())
    }
}
```

and use it as (or create own button extension with button builder to hide those unneeded curls)

```
Button(action: {
        // action here
    }){}
    .buttonStyle(MyStyle(label: Text("Hello")))
```

Tested with Xcode 13.2 / iOS 15.2

[image]

Comment: Too bad you have to have that trailing close on the `Button` initializer though for its label… Any way around that?

Comment: Making a custom `init(action:)` which calls `self.init("", action: action)` seems to be working